# Headphone jack works but speakers do not work Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04, sound, speakers

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I noticed I can't get the speakers to work.

I'm using an HP laptop that's 2 years old which previously had a Windows 10 installation (Speakers were working fine in Win10 with Realtek drivers). When I use the headphone jack, the sound works just fine but when I unplug them nothing comes from the speakers. The only option I see under Settings > Input Device is the Headphones.

Here is a screenshot of my Sound settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMPhU.jpg

Comment: Please attach your sound settings screenshot.

Comment: Hello! here is my screenshot of my sound settings: https://imgur.com/sHtwePp.jpg Sorry I am new with this.